# Eclipse Juno using Alt+Shift+X, J

Tags: eclipse-juno

I usually run java classes (with main() ) with keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> in my Eclipse Indigo.
I recently I started using Eclipse Juno and it seems to rather not work. Is this a bug in eclipse juno?

My Eclipse build number is:

```
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this an Eclipse bug?

===================================

Updated with my eclipse Juno key mappings screen shot

[image: My Eclipse Juno Key Mappings List]

Comment: Read the manual. Or check preferences >> hotkeys.

Comment: Weird, I thought it's supposed to be: `Alt+Shift+X R` - but anyways, you can configure eclipse to use any shortcut you like!

Comment: Look at the key bindings of your eclipse.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I am aware of manuals. There is no option to go from Preferences > Hot Keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indeed is a bug in Eclipse 4.
Try this `Alt + Shift + X Esc J`

Press `Alt + Shift + X` when the popup appears hit `Esc` and then quickly follow it up with `J`. This works for me.

I will find the bug raised in eclipse and attach the link here.

Comment: thanks. It's spot on. Strange that I googled it but could not find on the main page about the bug. And the work around works too.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=218881#c25), you need to set the 'when' binding of the shortcut to 'In Dialog and Windows'

> Window > Preferences > General > Keys, then filtered for 'Shift+alt+x'
>   then for each command I changed When field from 'In windows' to 'In
>   dialogs and windows'. The same for 'shift+alt+d'

Answer (score 1):

1. click on "perspective" under "Window"
2. Expand "general" and look for "keys"
3. This will list all the key bindings for eclipse commands
4. Search for "Run Java Application" under "Commands" column.
5. The key binding might be set to something else rather than Alt+Shift+X,J.
6. You can set the key binding to Alt+Shift+X,J or any other combination which you prefer.

Comment: I did not see the 1st option that you have specified in eclipse; I see a Window > Open Perspective option but not the one that you have specified. I have edited my question to show to show the screen shot as well. The key mappings are actually correct. By the way you can open the key mappings simply with "Ctrl+Shift+L"

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Java class, click Ctrl+F11 automatically your JAVA Program will run.